# Here maps api JS => optimizar waypoints

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

tengo desarrollado en google maps api un script donde obtiene x cantidad de waypoints y lo manda a crear una ruta con el parametro optimizacion. Ahora quiero hacer lo mismo en HERE MAPS , con la API JS y no estoy encontrando la forma.

Es decir necesito enviarle un punto de salida , uno de llegada y ne el medio X cantidad de waypoints y que here maps me los ordene de la mejor forma para crear la ruta ( COMO HACE GOOGLE ) . Alguien lo ha realizado ? Estuve llendo la documentación y buscando y no encontre nada.

Comment: google maps ofrece waypoints ordenados con la mejor ruta mediante muy pocas lineas de codigo, tu interes por hacerlo con here maps sera imagino meramente para aprender sobre here maps cierto?, porque considero que la mejor opcion para los way points es google maps, de todas formas, te doy la bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, permíteme introducirte un poco al sitio, primero deberia mostrarte el [tour], luego deberias leer [ask], para poder que futuras preguntas que hagas sean validas en el sitio, pues esta pregunta no cumple con las reglas del sitio, recomiendo su edicion.

Comment: Hola !! EL problema de google maps es que solamenta son hasta 25 waypoint ( incluyendo salida y destino ) . Yo necesito manipular alrededor de 70.

Gracias por la informacion extra ! Ya estoy ingresando a los enlaces que pasaste !